Evans PDEs, chapter 7, why is $|B[u,u;t]|\leq C \|u\|_{L^2(\mathbb{R}^n,\mathbb{R}^m)}^2$?
This is likely a trivial question, but I had to check one thing on Evans PDEs chapter 7, and I got stuck verifying one specific inequality. Evans defines the bilinear form
$$B[u,v;t] := \int_{\mathbb{R}^n}\sum_{j=1}^n \left(B_j(.,t)u_{x_j}\right)\cdot v dx$$
for $u,v\in H^1(\mathbb{R}^n,\mathbb{R}^n)$, and a bit later states that
$$|B[u,u;t]|\leq C\|u\|_{L^2(\mathbb{R}^n,\mathbb{R}^m)}^2$$
where each $B_j$ is an $m\times $ matrix depending on $t$ and $x$ such that
$$\sup_{\mathbb{R}^n\times\left[0, T\right]}\left(|B_j|, |D_{x,t}B_j|, |D_{x,t}^2 B_j|\right) < \infty$$
for all $j = 1,\dots,n$.
What I am missing is how can you get rid of $u$'s derivatives $u_{x_j}$ in the estimation s.t. you end up with $u$'s $L^2\left(\mathbb{R}^n, \mathbb{R}^m\right)$ norm?
Evans deduces such an inequality for any $v\in C_c^\infty(\mathbb{R}^n, \mathbb{R}^m)$, and concludes that by approximation such an inequality holds for $u^\epsilon$, where $u^\epsilon = \eta_\epsilon\ast u, 0 < \epsilon\leq 1$, where I am assuming that $\eta_\epsilon$ is the standard mollifier. Can you conclude
$$|B[u,u;t]|\leq C\|u\|_{L^2(\mathbb{R}^n,\mathbb{R}^m)}^2$$
based on
$$|B[u^\epsilon,u^\epsilon;t]|\leq C\|u^\epsilon\|_{L^2(\mathbb{R}^n,\mathbb{R}^m)}^2$$
by some approximation argument?

Maybe the missing step is something like this:
$$
\int_{\mathbb R^n} B_j u_{x_j} u = 
\int_{\mathbb R^n} B_j \frac\partial{\partial x_j}(u^2)
=-\int_{\mathbb R^n} (\frac\partial{\partial x_j}B_j) u^2.
$$

Where (discounting the missing constant $1/2$) we further assume that $u^2$ is also in $H^1(\mathbb{R}^n,\mathbb{R}^m)$ as well? In any case, nice observation!

I think $u\in H^1$ is enough as $B$ and its derivatives is in $L^\infty$.

Why? It has been some time since I've really used Sobolev spaces, so I don't see immediately why $u^2$ would be in $H^1$.

If $u\in H^1$ all the integrals in my answer exist. $u^2$ is not in $H^1$ in general.

Just to recap, is the last step in your chain of equalities a proper integration by parts, or is it the definition of a weak derivative? If it is the former, why does the (limit) boundary integral vanish? If it is the latter, what is the object we are claiming to have a weak derivative?

This is the part which has to be proven first for $u \in C_c^\infty$. It is integration by parts.
